# macOS, Swift: Find current user's Applications directory (not the global "/Applications" directory)

Tags: swift, macos

On macOS in Swift, how can I obtain the name of the current user's Applications directory?

In other words, **NOT** the global "/Applications" directory, but the one just for the current user, for example "/Users/eric/Applications" or perhaps "/Users/eric/Library/Containers/com.eric.MyApp/Data/Applications"

The following code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let listOfSearchPathDirectory: [FileManager.SearchPathDirectory] = [
            .applicationDirectory,
            .allApplicationsDirectory
        ]

        let listOfSearchPathDomainMask = [
            FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
        ]

        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        for searchPathDirectory in listOfSearchPathDirectory {
            print("    A [\(searchPathDirectory.rawValue)]")

            for searchPathDomainMask in listOfSearchPathDomainMask {
                for url in fileManager.urls(for: searchPathDirectory, in: searchPathDomainMask) {
                    print("        B [\(url)]")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

generates output like this:

```
A [1]
    B [file:///Users/eric/Library/Containers/com.eric.MyApp/Data/Applications/]
A [100]
    B [file:///Users/eric/Library/Containers/com.eric.MyApp/Data/Applications/]
    B [file:///Users/eric/Library/Containers/com.eric.MyApp/Data/Applications/Utilities/]
    B [file:///Users/eric/Library/Containers/com.eric.MyApp/Data/Developer/Applications/]
    B [file:///Users/eric/Library/Containers/com.eric.MyApp/Data/Applications/Demos/]
```

which includes what I thought would be the correct value:

```
file:///Users/eric/Library/Containers/com.eric.MyApp/Data/Applications/
```

but when I run the application, that directory does not exist.

In fact if I list the contents of its parent directory by typing this in the Terminal application:

```
ls -l /Users/eric/Library/Containers/com.eric.MyApp/Data
```

I get the following, but this does NOT include the expected directory "Applications":

```
> lrwxr-xr-x   1 eric  staff   19 22 Jun 11:37 Desktop -> ../../../../Desktop
> drwx------   3 eric  staff   96 22 Jun 11:37 Documents
> lrwxr-xr-x   1 eric  staff   21 22 Jun 11:37 Downloads -> ../../../../Downloads
> drwx------  30 eric  staff  960 22 Jun 11:37 Library
> lrwxr-xr-x   1 eric  staff   18 22 Jun 11:37 Movies -> ../../../../Movies
> lrwxr-xr-x   1 eric  staff   17 22 Jun 11:37 Music -> ../../../../Music
> lrwxr-xr-x   1 eric  staff   20 22 Jun 11:37 Pictures -> ../../../../Pictures
```

I was hoping to have also seen a line like this:

```
> lrwxr-xr-x   1 eric  staff   19 22 Jun 11:37 Applications -> ../../../../Applications
```

Anyone know how I can tell the code that I want this local Applications directory to exist?

Many thanks

Comment: Use SearchPathDirectory.userDirectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the directory with

```
do {
    let userApplicationDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationDirectory, 
                                                                in: .userDomainMask, 
                                                    appropriateFor: nil, 
                                                            create: true)
    print(userApplicationDirectory)
} catch { print(error)}
```

If the directory is missing it will be created.

If the app is sandboxed it points to `.../Data/Applications` in the container, otherwise to `~/Applications`

Comment: I added your lines of code, and it does indeed create the directory ".../Data/Applications", but the thing is, the files in the directory "/Users/eric/Applications" (for example SomeApp.app) are NOT copied to the ".../Data/Applications" directory.  I had hoped that ".../Data/Applications" would become a symbolic link to the directory "/Users/eric/Applications"

Comment: This behavior is intended if the app is sandboxed. In this case both folders are separated and you don't have access to `~/Applications`